# Loading position of javascript in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-ujs

There are two pieces of my application that seem to require that I load my javascript at different points.

1. Omniauth works when I place `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`  within `<head></head>`.
2. Shubox (js library used to upload photos) works when I place `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`  just before `</body>`.

Each of the two does not work when the javascript is loaded where the other requires. So, if I place the javascript line at the end of the body, omniauth does not work.

I can provide additional information if needed. Thank you in advance.

**application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
    <body data-shubox="<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>">
    <% if flash.any? %>
      <% flash.each do |key, value| -%>
        <section class="flash flash__<%= key %>"><%= value.html_safe %></section>
      <% end -%>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right before body ends should work for both, do u see some error for omniauth in that case?

Comment: Right before body ends works for omniauth if I include require("@rails/ujs").start() in application.js. If I do that however, the page that uses Shubox throws this error: "Error: rails-ujs has already been loaded!"

Comment: Can you share application.js and the head and relevant body parts in application.html.erb?

Comment: Edited to include relevant parts of each file

Comment: Ah this has to do with turbolinks. Move application.js to head, and listen to turbo load event to load libs that need the dom ready like shubox

Answer (score 0):

Because of Turbolinks your application.js needs to be in the head tag, [otherwise it is evaluated twice](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements) . This can cause a problem with libraries that expect your DOM to be loaded when you initialize them - which I think is your problem with shubox.

So you should put something like this in your application.js (if you are using Turbolinks 5, for earlier version the event is called `page:load`)

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',() => {
   new Shubox('#avatar', { key: "abcde-qwerty-12345" })
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create 2 `packs` if you need them in different places:

javascript/packs/the_one_with_turbolink.js
javascript/packs/the_one_with_shubox.js

then you can do

`javascript_pack_tag :the_one_with_turbolinks`

and

`javascript_pack_tag :the_one_with_shubox`